# CORS compliant $.ajax post call with complex json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cors

I understand CORS is a well discussed topic in stackoverflow but I just cannot find a answer for my particular case. I need to post a complex json (i.e. with more than 1 hierarchy, so I have to stringify it and send it as text) to a CORS server, the server is configured to accept CORS call (pls check the option response) but I keep getting CORS error, is there anything I am doing wrongly? any thought? thanks

```
$.ajax({
        url: '//example.com/input',
        type: 'post',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
          outer: [
            {
              inner: {
                data: "somedata"
              }
            }
          ],
        })
      });
```

OPTION

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →Content-Type, If-Match
Access-Control-Allow-Max-Age →21600
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →OPTIONS, GET, POST, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Allow →OPTIONS, GET, POST, HEAD
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →0
Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8
Date →Wed, 30 Apr 2014 20:04:45 GMT
```

the error I am getting is:

```
 cannot load exampe.com/input. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'another.com'; is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: Do you own the server side code? If so, can you post what the server handler/controller action looks like?

Comment: what's the return code you are getting from the server? and is the JSON serialization returning any errors?

Comment: I cannot share the server side code I am afraid, the json serialization seems to be fine but I am getting following error

cannot load http://exampe.com/input. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.another.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 3):

You must return an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response to the underlying POST request as well (not just the preflight/OPTIONS).  Based on the content of your question, I can only assume you are not doing that.

Comment: the server did send the header, above response is telling this?

Access-Control-Allow-Methods →OPTIONS, GET, POST, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*

Comment: That looks like a response to the preflight/OPTIONS, not the underlying POST.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I thought how CORS works is: while we are trying to do a POST, the browser actually will send a pre-flight request i.e. OPTION to the backend to get the headers origin and etc? as I am getting above error, so the POST request was not actually sent out (therefore no response)

Comment: You haven't listed any error in your question.  You'll need to include the actual error along with a transcript of network requests in your question.

Comment: I have updated my original post with the error, not sure why I am still getting this error, might be related to the content-type I specified? btw, in the server, I have enalbed 'Content-Type' in the CORS server (as you can see from the option response )

Comment: @JohnZ how sure are you that there is not actual POST request sent out? It is possible for the preflight request to succeed and the subsequent POST request to fail. In that case, there will an actual POST request sent to the server, followed by a response back to the client. (However, in the case of CORS failure, the browser simply refuses to let JS see the POST response.) It looks like that's what is happening: your OPTIONS preflight response is perfect, but then the actual POST isn't CORS-compliant (i.e., it's missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`).